# angulardart and django_rest. unable to get data from the backend

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework

[this example is from a tutorial](https://angulardart.dev/guide/server-communication) and I get an error
**Exception: Server error; cause: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'**

terminal pycharm backend gives data code 200

[09/Feb/2020 11:45:48] "GET /adverts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 492

```
  class Hero {
  final int id;
  String name;

  Hero(this.id, this.name);

  factory Hero.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> hero) =>
      Hero(_toInt(hero['id']), hero['name']);

  Map toJson() => {'id': id, 'name': name};
}

int _toInt(id) => id is int ? id : int.parse(id);

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'hero.dart';

class HeroService {
  static final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  static const _heroesUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/heroes'; // URL to 
 web API
  final Client _http;

  HeroService(this._http);

  Future<List<Hero>> getAll() async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.get(_heroesUrl);
      final heroes = (_extractData(response) as List)
          .map((value) => Hero.fromJson(value))
          .toList();
      return heroes;
    } catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  Future<Hero> create(String name) async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.post(_heroesUrl,
          headers: _headers, body: json.encode({'name': name}));
      return Hero.fromJson(_extractData(response));
    } catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  dynamic _extractData(Response resp) => json.decode(resp.body)['data'];

  Exception _handleError(dynamic e) {
    print(e); // for demo purposes only
    return Exception('Server error; cause: $e');
  }
}
```

[image: rest_api it's work to webstorm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have json this -> data: and to get the data you need from the string -> dynamic _extractData (Response resp) => json.decode (resp.body) **['data']**; delete **['data']** or edit JSON generation django_rest, if you have information on how to get a JSON like {'data':[ ]} in drf, I'm happy to read it